# UWP localize print dialog

Tags: printing, uwp, localization

Using the "Printing" project from the "Windows-universal-samples-master" examples on GitHub... scenario 4 is showing:

```
            displayedOptions.Add(Windows.Graphics.Printing.StandardPrintTaskOptions.CustomPageRanges);
            printTask.Options.PageRangeOptions.AllowCurrentPage = true;
            printTask.Options.PageRangeOptions.AllowAllPages = true;
            printTask.Options.PageRangeOptions.AllowCustomSetOfPages = true;
```

My question is how do you localize these settings of the print dialog?
I did set my primary language to French in Control Panel but the print dialog still shows the options in English ("All pages", "Custom range", "Page range"...).

Comment: I have tested with the code sample and print dialog display with correct language. please check if have set the Windows display language as `France` within setting page.

Comment: Turns out that the "Preferred languages" priorities are ignored for the Windows print dialog, but taken into account by the app.  It's a little inconsistent.  As mentionned by Nico, the "Windows display language" setting had to be changed as well.  Setting the "Preferred language" to French was not sufficient (even though DELL printer specific sub-dialog would correctly translate!).

Comment: Yep, Setting the "Preferred language" to French was not sufficient,  the "Windows display language" setting had to be changed as well. May I converter this to the reply for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the **Preferred language** to French was not sufficient, you need set the **Windows display language** as `France` as well.

[image]